# Bootrap datepicker date comparison is wrong (UK/US formatting error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, momentjs

I am trying to compare two dates. One is inputted by the user when creating a new point, which has a date field, the model is shown below.

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

The other is set by a filter using a datepicker.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="end">Start date:</label><br />
    <div class='input-group date' id='dt1'>
        @Html.TextBox("StartDateFilter", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dt1').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'en-GB',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });
</script>
```

I then try and compare these two dates using a simple if statement like so:

```
if (dateInput >= dateFilter)
```

The issue I am having however, is that the inputted format remains in the UK standard like 04/01/2015 (4th Jan) but the fltered date from the datepicker gets sent in the US format like 12/08/2015 (8th Dec), so when comparing these it is not correct.

How can I compare these so that they will compare correctly? I am using this in a UK environment, so as long as the user only sees the UK formatting, it doesn't matter what happens behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours on this, as soon as I post on here, I seem to have had a brainwave that works. I managed to convert the US time from the datepicker to a UK format and then compare these. I previously tried this but realised I had set the culture wrong so I was converting from a US format to a US format. I have fixed this now and it works! :D

Sorry for the unecessary question now!

```
DateTime ukDateTimeFormat = DateTime.Parse(startDateFilter.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```